# Can't "pull" with smartgit, "fetch only" is available

Tags: git, git-pull, smartgit

I use **SmartGit** as a GUI for git. But so far, I always have the same problem.
In my projects (all of them), *I can't pull*, the button is disabled, it's only the "fetch only" button which is available.

But if I run the command `git pull origin master` it *works fine* and I can continue to use SmartGit as usual.

How to get rid of this problem ?

[image]

Comment: A comment about the downvote would be appreciated

Comment: What's shown when you hover the mouse over the blue (i) icon?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Make sure that your `master` is tracking `origin/master`. You may use **Set Tracked Branch** in the **Branches** view to configure tracking.